# Check two variable limit exists. $\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{xy^2\cos y}{x^2 + y^4}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$0 \le \left\vert \dfrac{xy^2\cos y}{x^2 + y^4} \right\vert \le \left\vert\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}\right\vert \le\left\vert\dfrac{x(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}\right\vert = |x|$,

and if I $\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}$ $0$ and $|x|$, they will both go to $0$, and so I can know that given formula is continuous and the limit value will be $0$.

But it is not quite right, and I know there are counterexamples.

Could you let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please avoid the usage of display style math on the question title. See [Guidelines for good use of MathJax on question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233) for more information.

Comment: Oh, sorry and thank you for letting me know soupless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|y|\leqslant1$, then $y^4\leqslant y^2$, and therefore $\frac1{x^2+y^4}\geqslant\frac1{x^2+y^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$y^{4} < y^{2}$ for $|y|<1$. So $\frac  1{x^{2}+y^{4}} >\frac  1{x^{2}+y^{2}}$